# How to plot a stack of matrices or 3d volume in r

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have a 3d matrix of numbers (16x16x5). One layer is depicted by following matrix:

```
m = matrix (sample(0:127,256,replace=TRUE), nrow=16)
```

Similar 5 matrices are there in the stack.

1. How can I depict them as R objects? Following code does not work:

   ```
   m = list(list(128),list(128), list(128), list(128), list(128))
   for(i in 1:5) m[i] = matrix (sample(0:127,256,replace=TRUE), nrow=10)
   ```
2. How can I plot them so that each matrix is plotted as a contour-plot with semitransparent color (only one shade needed, eg gray) and 5 matrices are plotted on top of each other. It should be preferably possible to move the plot with mouse (as with plot3d or rgl.surface of rgl).

The question is similar to that of volume rendering as on this page: http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/smooth3.html
or on this page: [How can I visualize volume data as shown here, in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363537/how-can-i-visualize-volume-data-as-shown-here-in-matlab)

Edit: following works to produce the 3d matrix:

```
array(sample(0:127,256*5,replace=TRUE), c(16,16,5))
```

Comment: The function `array` is mentioned in the documentation for `matrix`.

Comment: Thanks. {array(sample(0:127,256*5,replace=TRUE), c(16,16,5))} works. I have added this in the question.

Comment: You might try looking at the `plot3D` package.

Comment: I think you need to be more thoughtful about how the the values are handled. Just plotting 'something" will not create the surfaces in the examples you point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
require(rgl)

plot3d(rep(1:128, 128*5),
   rep(1:128,each=128*5), 
   rep(1:5, 128*128), 
   col=colorRampPalette(c(rgb(1,0,0,.1), rgb(0,0,1,.1)), alpha=TRUE)(128)[ m ])
```

Comment: This is the plot that I want, but I am getting this error: Error in colorRamp(colors, ...) : unused argument(s) (alpha = TRUE). I am using version 2.15.1 on Debian Stable Linux. Also how to plot this with { array(sample(0:127,256*5,replace=TRUE), c(16,16,5)) }

Comment: [m] will provide the array input. The plot is working perfectly. Thanks very much.

Comment: The code is working without "alpha=TRUE", else it gives above mentioned error. Can I correct this.

Comment: Don't know. I'm two versions of R ahead of you and 'alpha' is definitely an acceptable argument for `colorRamp` and by extension of `colorRampPalatte`. Read your help page?

Comment: In my version ?colorRamp or ?colorRampPalette page, there is no alpha (I tried finding it by using '/'). There is an alpha() function found on ?alpha. USAGE: alpha(color,alpha). ARGUMENTS: color: color, alpha: alpha level [0,1]. There is also an col2rgb(col, alpha) function as also an rgb function which has alpha. Can that be used?

Comment: I doubt it can be used in your version, since the alpha=TRUE is specifcally designed to allow col2rgb input with alpha values. Does your version of rgl support transparency?

Comment: r-cran-rgl version 0.92.798-1+deb7u1 is installed here. Also how can I reduce the heights of 5 surfaces, if want to bring them closer to each other?

Comment: Yah know, sometimes I get pretty tired of requests to read the help pages for packages for other people: `help(package='rgl');  aspect3d(1,1,.3)`

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Thanks and best wishes to you.